# Boolean operators exercise

Tags: boolean, operators

I am in an exercise of Boolean operators and I do not understand why:

```
not not True or False and not True = True
```

I understand:

```
not not True = True
True or False = False
False and not True = False
```

**`not not True or False and not True = False`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, `and` is given higher precedence than `or`, so your expression is equivalent to

```
(not not True) or (False and not True) == True or (False and False)
                                       == True or False
                                       == True
```

Answer (score 0):

Precedence:

```
NOT >  AND > OR
```

Therefore

```
not not True or False and not True = True
```

Just like:

```
2 + 3 * 3 - 1 = 10 and not 14.
```